# How to handle click checkbox without parent event in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a table with checkbox as image bellow:
[table with checkbox example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFw9B.png)

And example code:

```
<tbody>
<tr @click="goDetail">
  <th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" /></th>
  <td>Mark</td>
  <td>Otto</td>
  <td>mdo</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">2</th>
  <td>Jacob</td>
  <td>Thornton</td>
  <td>fat</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th scope="row">3</th>
  <td>Larry</td>
  <td>the Bird</td>
  <td>twitter</td>
</tr>
```

Currently, when click to  will call event: goDetail.

But, I want when click on the checkbox inside it will also call goDetail().
So, why i can prevent this.

I want to click anywhere on the  tag (except the checkbox) that will call goDetail().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Event Modifiers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) in vue.js.

```js
<input type="checkbox" v-on:click.stop />
```

or

```js
<input type="checkbox" @click.stop />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}/>
```